# Rubik's Cube and the symmetric group

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, rubiks-cube

I have a slightly unique question:

Using the fact that no permutation of $S_n$ can be both odd or even, why can we conclude that there is no way to rearrange a Rubik's Cube so that it swaps two corners but leaves all other pieces in the same location?

Comment: Because any valid move you can do on a rubics cube is an even permutation, but swapping two corners is an odd one. Chaining even permutations will give again an even one. So you can never reach at a state which was reached by an odd permutation.